# How to change layout by pressing the button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to bring a new layout by pressing a button in my android app. Here is the code piece:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_layout, null);

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // What should I write here to prompt empty_layout?
    }
}
```

I dont know how to use "promptView". Can you give me some insight please?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Use addView() from View class or may be you can use     setContentView(promtView);

Comment: @Simon I didnt know that it is that much easy. It seems it really worked ! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its the whole view of your screen then use

```
setContentView(prompView);
```

If its only a portion of a view then use

```
yourPortionViewContainer.addView(prompView);
```

Or may be you could use Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

you should create Intent to open new Activity or create Fragment and let FragmentManager show it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your question correctly but what I would do to add a layout when a button is pressed is to do it programmatically like this:

```
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)//assuming u gave the main layout an id of mainLayout in your XML file
    public void onClick(View v) {
          LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
          LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);//create variable to store layout parameters
          layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);//set orientation of layout
          layout.setLayoutParams(params);//set layout parameters
          mainLayout.addView(layout);//add the newly created layout to the already existing layout
}
```